# getting ip address from host name in BlackBerry 6

Tags: blackberry, ip, ip-address, host

Please let me know whether there is way to get  the IP address of server from it's domain name.
for example:

Domain name is : http://www.gmail.com

then i want api like

public String getIPAddress(String hostname)
{
Some code here

return ipAddress;
}

I am using Blackberry 6 api, which does not have InetAddress class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there is an API available in BB

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-remote-ip-address-given-its-hostname/td-p/171164

Comment: SO there is no way to get ip address from host name in blackberry? how about writing our own class like INetAddress for Blackberry ?